# Automatically updating corresponding collection in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

My database has two tables:

```
Users
    UserId        PK

Likes
    LikeId        PK
    LikedUserId   FK
    LikingUserId  FK
```

These tables represent user 'likes'. Likes are directional - user A likes user B, but user B does not like user A.

I am mapping with NHibernate like this:

```
<class name="User" table="Users">
    <id name="UserId">
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>

    <idbag name="LikedBy" table="Likes" inverse="true">
        <collection-id column="LikeId" type="guid">
            <generator class="guid.comb"/>
        </collection-id>
        <key column="LikedUserId"/>
        <many-to-many column="LikingUserId" class="User"/>
    </idbag>

    <idbag name="Liking" table="Likes">
        <collection-id column="LikeId" type="guid">
            <generator class="guid.comb"/>
        </collection-id>
        <key column="LikingUserId"/>
        <many-to-many column="LikedUserId" class="User"/>
    </idbag>
</class>
```

Corresponding to this class:

```
public class User 
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> LikedBy { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Liking { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine. However, the `Liking` and `LikedBy` collections for two different users can get out of sync. For instance:

```
using (var session = new NHibHelp.OpenSession())
{
    var user1 = session.GetById<User>(id1);
    var user2 = session.GetById<User>(id2);

    int initialCount = user2.LikedBy.Count();

    user1.Liking.Add(user2);
    session.Update(user1);

    int finalCount = user2.LikedBy.Count();

    Assert.AreEqual(initalCount,finalCount); // passes
}
```

So if I add to the `Liking` collection of one user, the `LikedBy` collection of another user is not updated. To have it updated, I need to do `Session.Refresh()`.

This isn't ideal. I'm quite new to NHibernate, so I don't know if there is another solution - is there anything better I can do? For instance, is it possible to map this scenario in such a way that `LikedBy` is automatically updated when appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a method to the `User` class that syncs both collections:

```
public class User 
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> LikedBy { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Liking { get; set; }

    public void Like(User user) 
    {
       this.Liking.Add(user);
       user.LikedBy.Add(this);
    }
}
```

You may also make this collections readonly to an external code:

```
private ICollection<User> likedBy;
private ICollection<User> liking;

public IEnumerable<User> LikedBy { get { return this.likedBy; } }
public IEnumerable<User> Liking { get { return this.liking; } }

<idbag access="field.camelcase" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution might be neat, but I have one concern: What happens when the `user.LikedBy` collection has not been loaded? Is its content pulled from the database before the new element is added? This could be an efficiency problem in cases where we don't care about the content of the other collection.

Comment: Yes, NHibernate will load its content. If it is an issue for you, then you probably could replace `User` entity in the collection by `Like` entity (that is more lightweight). Another apporach is to insert `Like` entity in database and update your collection manually (so, you read likes using `User.Liking/LikedBy` and update using `session.Save(new Like { Liking = user1, Liked = user2 });`).